# Why can a variable declared using 'var' be null in null-safe dart?

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

I'm copying this from the [docs](https://dart.dev/null-safety#creating-variables)

```
// In null-safe Dart, none of these can ever be null.
var i = 42; // Inferred to be an int.
String name = getFileName();
final b = Foo();
```

But I'm running the code below in a [null-safe dartpad](https://nullsafety.dartpad.dev/), and it compiles.

```
void main() {
  var x = null;
  print(x);
}
```

Is this a documentation error or am I missing something?

Comment: `var` declares a variable whose type should be inferred. It does not impose any type constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example are not close to what the documentation are trying to explain. Try this instead:

```
void main() {
  var x = 42;
  x = null; // Error: A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int' - line 3
  print(x);
}
```

The reason is that `var x = 42` is "Inferred to be an `int`" and not `int?`.

In your example, what happens is that `var x = null` are resolved so `x` are seen as the type `dynamic` since Dart have no clue about what type you are trying to use. Since `dynamic` can have the value `null` you are good to go.